# ADFS OWIN authentication not invoked in local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, adfs

I am trying to determine how to get an MVC application set up to authenticate against an on-premise ADFS server. I am using the Azure AD sample found at [the Github Azure Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation) and altered it as described in [Vittorio Bertocci's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/29/use-the-owin-security-components-in-asp-net-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs/) to use my app's RealmId and my organization's ADFS metadata endpoint. When I run the sample using IIS Express, the OWIN middleware is invoked and I get the redirect to the ADFS login screen.

However, The app I am working on needs to run in IIS so I am trying to configure my sample app in local IIS. When I run the sample in local IIS, there is no redirect to ADFS and the windows (Kerberos) identity is returned instead. How do I make sure that the OWIN middleware is invoked by IIS? The app pool is running in Integrated v4.0 mode.

This is the code in my Startup.Auth.cs:

```
private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string metadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = metadata,
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Authentication tab in IIS set to for your application?

Have you got Forms or Windows Authentication enabled?

What happens if the only item enabled is Anonymous?

Comment: Right now, I have all authentication modes disabled except Windows Authentication. This must have been the issue, because when I switched to only Anonymous enabled it looks like it is redirecting to ADFS.